# Unknown file appear while trying to load image data set and convert it into array

Tags: python, image, keras, directory, dataset

I'm trying to load a data set of images and convert it into array for further processing, but it keeps give me an error with a file that doesn't exist in my data set. I'm using PyCharm on Windows 10.

This is the error:

> [INFO] Loading images ...
>
> [INFO] Processing 00416648-be6e-4bd4-bc8d-82f43f8a7240___GCREC_Bact.Sp
>   3110.JPG ...
>
> Error : [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid:
>   'C:\Users\vipek\Desktop\PlantVillage\Tomato_Bacterial_spot\00416648-be6e-4bd4-bc8d-82f43f8a7240___GCREC_Bact.Sp
>   3110.JPG'

The image is not in my data set.

```
from typing import List

import numpy as np
import pickle
import cv2
from os import listdir
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
from keras import backend as k
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path

EPOCHS = 25
INIT_LR = 1e-3
BS = 32
default_image_size = tuple((256, 256))
image_size = 0
directory_root = Path("C:/Users/vipek/Desktop/PlantVillage")
width = 256
height = 56
depth = 3


def convert_image_to_array(image_dir):
    try:
        images = cv2.imread(image_dir)
        if images is not None:
            images = cv2.resize(images, default_image_size)
            return img_to_array(images)
        else:
            return np.array([])
    except Exception as E:
        print(f"Error : {E}")
        return None


image_list, label_list = [], []
try:
    print("[INFO] Loading images ...")
    root_dir: List[str] = listdir(directory_root)

    for plant_folder in root_dir:
        plant_disease_folder_list = listdir(directory_root / plant_folder)

        for plant_disease_folder in plant_disease_folder_list:
            print(f"[INFO] Processing {plant_disease_folder} ...")
            plant_disease_image_list = listdir(directory_root / plant_folder / plant_disease_folder)

            for image in plant_disease_image_list[:200]:
                image_directory = f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}/{plant_disease_folder}/{image}"
                if image_directory.endswith(".jpg"):
                    label_list.append(plant_disease_folder)
    print("[INFO] Image loading completed")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error : {e}")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Some of your code in your question is wrong. e.g. this line `plant_disease_folder_list = listdir(directory_root / plant_folder)`

I suppose it is `f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}"`, right?

2. The code in your question is not complete. It would not trigger the error. You must have left out the part that calls the function `convert_image_to_array`
3. Based on the error message, you are probably trying to change the current directory to a path of a jpg file. If it's true, you simply need to add a `os.path.isdir` to make sure you are passing only directory paths to the function
4. Do not construct path using `f"{..,}"` syntax. You should use `os.path.join` instead. e.g. `f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}/{plant_disease_folder}/{image}` can be rewritten as `os.path.join(directory_root, plant_folder, plant_disease_folder, image)`

Comment: I change it back to `f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}"` and i do have the function `convert_image_to_array`, its up there after the import list, im still getting the error after changing it. The thing is where should i put `os.path.isdir` and `os.path.join`? Im new to this :D

Answer (score 0):

I did this same project if you have the same dataset as mine. Then the problem lies in this line of the code `plant_disease_image_list = listdir(directory_root / plant_folder / plant_disease_folder)` instead make it as `plant_disease_image_list = listdir(directory_root / plant_folder)`.